# How to add user/ADGroup to a policy in GPO using Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I had search around the internet and only found how to use Carbon module to edit Local Policy. But I need to edit Group Policy actually

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDTq2.png) Want to do the same thing as the picture but using script (GPO)

[GPO name and ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFlgw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the short answer is still **you can't**.

Group policy objects are kind of a mess with:

- The policy objects: `\\domain.com\sysvol\policies\{GPO-GUID}\`
- Each require PolicyDefinition files, which can be custom-created: `\\domain.com\sysvol\policies\PolicyDefinitions\*.admx`
- Which in turn each require a matching localized language definition: `\\domain.com\sysvol\policies\PolicyDefinitions\en-US\*.adml`

Either use the group policy management mmc tool, or find the registry keys that correspond to the gpo settings you want, and change them via powershell.